# PHPUnit depends doesn't pass data

Tags: php, function, scope, phpunit

I have a simple problem, I can't pass data from one function to another. This is my code:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider myProvider
 */
public function testIfPathIsString($path){
    $isValid = (is_string($path)) ? true : false;
    $this->assertEquals(true, $isValid);
    return $path;
}

/**
 * @depends testIfPathIsString
 */
public function testIfFileExists($help){
    $exists = $this->fileController->checkIfFileExists($help);
    $this->assertEquals(true, $exists);
    return $help; 
}

public function myProvider()
{
    return array(
        array("C:/xampp/htdocs/mycustom.txt")
    );
}
```

First function gets path just fine but passing with annotation depends to second function fails, it sends null or empty.

I explicitly have one correct data path in dataset so that doesn't make any sense?

Comment: https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/183#issuecomment-816066

Comment: Couldn't got better answer :). Thx @Matteo